# Remove everything from output except between <p> tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that outputs content from individual blog posts with `the_content()`

Blog posts all consist of two things, a small gallery and some text:

```
<div class="gallery"><img></img>Blah Blah</div>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```

I'd like to split the gallery and the text and output the gallery in a div on the left and the text in a div on the right like this:

```
<div id="left">GALLERY CONTENT</div>
<div id="right">TEXT CONNTENT</div>
```

I have tried to do this with `strip_tags(the_content(), '<p>')` but this does not - it continues to output everything including the gallery.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear to me what you really want to do , and on to of it , you included some (very little ) source code from output, but to get a real shot at answering you need to include the relative code from the template  file.

( And +1 for understanding alone that you should **NOT TOUCH YOUR CORE FILES** )

Anyhow, I suspect that you only want to disable the `auto P` generated by wordrpess , so try

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

(add to functions.php in theme.)

alternatively , you could use

```
add_filter('use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false');
```

Which will just "reset" the gallery styling .

or even filter your own gallery styles , which allows you to target them better.

```
add_filter( 'gallery_style', 'my_own_gallery_style', 99 );

function my_own_gallery_style() {
    return "<div class='gallery'>"; // put your own
}
```

If it does not produce the right output for you, please include more specifics and / or more code .

There are of course more advanced ways to handle this , but Without more info it is difficult to target .

For example you can create your own gallery style by removing the original shortcode function, and then adding your own, but those are a bit more advanced techniques.

```
// deactivate WordPress function
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');

// activate your own own function
add_shortcode('gallery', 'my_own_gallery_shortcode');

// the own renamed function
function my_own_gallery_shortcode($attr) {
...
}
```

Now on the other hand , If you want to "catch" some parts of 'the_content' and display it in a loop in a different manner , you can always use a different technique, like described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16453657/1244126) on another answer .

Answer (score 0):

You are using `the_content` which displays the content instead of returning it.

Change your code to

```
strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<p>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem a while ago. Here's what I did (in `single.php`, which is where I had the problem):

```
if ( get_post_format() == 'gallery' ) :
    $content = get_the_content();
    $gallery_regex = '/\[gallery.*]/s'; //identify the [gallery] tags within the content

    //get gallery code
    $gallery = preg_match($gallery_regex, $content, $matches);
    $gallery = $matches[0];

    //remove gallery from content
    add_filter('the_content', function($content){
        $gallery_regex = '/\[gallery.*]\s*/s';
        return preg_replace($gallery_regex, ' ', $content);
    });

endif;
```

Basically, I used regex to remove the gallery tags from the content.

`$gallery` still contains the shortcode. We can't just randomly display it, or it'll actually *show* the shortcode. We need to execute it, which will show the output:

```
if ( get_post_format() == 'gallery' ) {
    echo '<div id="left">'. do_shortcode($gallery) .'</div>';
}
```

Your content no longer contains the gallery, so you can do this:

```
<div id="right"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```